# Как лучше хранить в MySQL значения timestamp из php?

Tags: типы-данных, php, mysql

В mysql есть такой тип как timestamp, но там бред какой-то. Хранить timestamp лучше в полях с типом строка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С типом integer

Comment: вот так "online INT(11) DEFAULT 00000000000"

Comment: А в строке не лучше?

Comment: Было б лучше - ответили бы "в строке лучше", не так ли?

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL в типах для поля есть timestamp, уж боюсь предположить для чего он предназначен :)

Comment: Вы сами то работали с ним?

Comment: работал, что вам не нравится в нем ?

Comment: Ну по идеи там должно храниться время в UNIX формате, а UNIX формат это кол-во секунд прошедших с начала UNIX эпохи, но там можно вставить определенные числа которые дают одинаковую дату хотя по логике даже это не возможно. А то что генерируется функцией time() в PHP то есть нормальный UNIX формат туда вообще не подходит...